# Arduino and MatLab Scope Issues

Tags: matlab, arduino, scope

I'm trying to access an Arduino object named `ard` from another `.m` file, and I am getting what I expected which is `Undefined function or variable 'ard'.`

For example, I need to create the arduino object from one `.m` file, and use it within another `.m` file.

The first `.m` file is simply where I create the object and have all general scripting.  The second `.m` file is a `function`, and within that function I try and pass the `ard` variable into one of its methods.

Script 1:

```
ard = arduino();

specificTest(13)
```

Script 2:

```
function specificTest(digiPin)
writeDigitalPin(ard,digiPin,1)
end
```

While I am on this subject, can I have multiple functions within one `.m` file?  If so this would solve the problem I imagine, as this is clearly a scope problem?

Basically, this is sudo code as my main aim is to have separate functions that I can access the Arduino object and its methods from within each function without instantiating it multiple times, which I imagine you cannot do as the Arduino object seems very complex.

The exact errors are as follows:

```
Undefined function or variable 'ard'.

Error in specificTest (line 2)
writeDigitalPin(ard,digiPin,1)

Error in generalTest (line 5)
specificTest(13)
```

Comment: This seems like pretty basic Matlab. I think that you can probably answer theses questions for yourself simply by spending a bit of time reading the [very good documentation on functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html). Or is there something specific that is unclear in the documentation?

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realise how in depth functions are in MatLab.  When ever I watch any MatLab tutorials, people only seem to use just one main function.  As the documentation illustrates, theres quite a few so I will have to have a good read.

Comment: Videos: [functions, subfunctions](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2007/12/21/matlab-basics-functions-and-subfunctions/) and [nested functions](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2008/02/01/matlab-basics-nested-functions/).